# Using the ShadowRoot of a component onAttach

Tags: dart, angular-dart

So I have this angular dart component:

```dart
@Component(...)
class TableCard implements AttachAware, ShadowRootAware {

  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    _shadowRoot = shadowRoot;
  }

  void attach() {
    someDiv = _shadowRoot.querySelector("#card");
  }
}
```

everytime I load the page and the `attach` function gets called, it says:

```
The null object does not have a method 'querySelector'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'querySelector'
Receiver: null
Arguments: ["#card"]
```

Is there a way to have the shadowRoot initialized for the `onAttach` call?

edit: Or maybe there is another interface that provides a function that is called later than `attach` ?

edit2: As a workaround I just do whatever I need to do with the shadowRoot in the `onShadowRoot` function.

Comment: Why are you unhappy with doing the work in `onShadowRoot`?

Comment: Yes `onShadowRoot` is called after, although initially thought this function was only to inject the shadowRoot. I thought I was potentially using the wrong method.

Comment: If your code depends on `shadowRoot` then I think it's just fine. If you want to have a more expressive name for the task, you can of course move the code to another method and call this method from `onShadowRoot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `onShadowRoot` is a good place for code that depends on the shadowRoot being initialized.